# Is there a (legitimate) website on which I can check to see if I have any unclaimed money from past bank accounts?

Tags: canada, bank-account, websites

It may seem silly, but I wonder if I've got a bank account out there in which I have unclaimed money.  Wouldn't that be cool?  How can I check?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The one I've seen recommended by Clark Howard is [missingmoney.com](http://missingmoney.com), takes your last name, and the state you want to search in, you can also add first name, but its optional.

Answer (score 9):

YMCbuzz: since your profile says you are in Canada, you are in luck.

Canadian banks must turn over their unclaimed accounts to the bank of Canada.

They have an [Unclaimed Balances](http://www.bank-banque-canada.ca/en/ucb/index.html) page that has a search feature to see if you have missing millions from long lost relatives.